# Plugin fails while eclipse run-as works

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, knime

What are some of the ways that an eclipse application in general, knime specifically, would "fail to create" a class when I install a jar.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the class because it runs within eclipse with the run as tool.  Bit when I export as a plugin or create an update site, the final plugin fails.  The class file is here below this error snippet.

*** Welcome to KNIME Analytics Platform v4.3.2.v202103051236 ***
*** Copyright by KNIME AG, Zurich, Switzerland ***

ERROR RepositoryManager Node ‘org.knime.examples.numberformatter.NumberFormatterNodeFactory’ from plugin ‘org.knime.examples.numberformatter’ could not be created. The corresponding plugin bundle could not be activated!

```
package org.knime.examples.numberformatter;

import org.knime.core.node.NodeDialogPane;
import org.knime.core.node.NodeFactory;
import org.knime.core.node.NodeView;

/**
 * This is an example implementation of the node factory of the
 * "NumberFormatterNode".
 * 
 * The node factory creates all classes the make up a node. Furthermore, it specifies if the
 * node has views or a dialog (both are optional). 
 *
 * @author KNIME GmbH, Konstanz, Germany
 */
public class NumberFormatterNodeFactory extends NodeFactory<NumberFormatterNodeModel> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public NumberFormatterNodeModel createNodeModel() {
        // Create and return a new node model.
        return new NumberFormatterNodeModel();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int getNrNodeViews() {
        // The number of views the node should have, in this cases there is none.
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public NodeView<NumberFormatterNodeModel> createNodeView(final int viewIndex,
            final NumberFormatterNodeModel nodeModel) {
        // We return null as this example node does not provide a view. Also see "getNrNodeViews()".
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasDialog() {
        // Indication whether the node has a dialog or not.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public NodeDialogPane createNodeDialogPane() {
        // This example node has a dialog, hence we create and return it here. Also see "hasDialog()".
        return new NumberFormatterNodeDialog();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The target project jre needed to match the knime jre version.